# How to debug a process that will be invoked by a running service using Visual Studio Debugger, C++

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, process

My situation is:

A running service (say process a.exe) will invoke an application (say process b.exe) at some point, with one variable parameter (say x, x is determined at run time). I want to debug: "b.exe x" with some breakpoints. "b.exe x" will run quickly and exit. Both a.exe and b.exe belong to the same C++ solution.

I can attach to a.exe in Debugger, but I don't know how to debug "b.exe x" which will be called by a.exe. I've ever thought to use a 2nd visual studio, but since b.exe will be invoked and finished quickly, there is no way for me to attach to it or "Start Debugging" it. Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

How do you have those two projects connected, also how are they precompiled? Do you just have a .exe or .dll of B? Then you cant. If you have raw code why not add B to A as a uncompiled library for debugging?

Comment: I  have raw code of both, they are in the same Solution.

Comment: Then just add it as a class library, make a resource link and you can just debug as usual?